# regex for shortforms

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex (JavaScript) which will extract shortforms from a string

for example  from below string

> Hibbs' essays in progress include "Anselm's Sacramental Imagination," "W.E.B. DuBois and Socratic Questioning," and "Everything That Rises Must Converge: Aquinas's Theological Re-formation of the Cardinal Virtues."

it will match `"W.E.B."` so the condition is it should have DOTs to seperate the letters

or from

> Marcih J. Robert II. Distinguished 
>   Professor of Electrical & Computer Engineering. Ph.D. (1977) Texas Tech University, B.S./M.S. Rose-Hulman Institute of Technology (1972/1973).

```
Ph.D.    
B.S.     
M.S.
```

will match

Thanks

Comment: Don't you want to match "J." and "II."?

Comment: it will be great if the could be matched.I want to break text on fullstops only. to identify fullstops the expression what I am using is /( \d+\.| [^\W\d_]\.|.)+?([!?.](?= |$)|$)/g

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This regex matches them but leaves line endings alone:

```
(\w+\.){2,}
```

(but also sub-strings like `MSc.`, `BSc.` etc. will not be matched!)

Comment: What is the significance of the comma after 2 ?

Comment: It means two or more. `A{2,}` is equivalent to `AA+`